# Warning appear after I solve a recursion question in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

I'm trying to implementing a code question below, but I got this type of warning. I don't know what happened since I could output the answer correctly. Below is my code and the warning:

```
continuous :: [Integer] -> Bool
continuous list = case list of 
            [] -> True
            [x,y] 
                 | abs (x-y) <= 1 -> True 
                 | otherwise -> False
            x:y:xs 
                | abs(x-y) <= 1 -> continuous (y:xs)
                | otherwise -> False 
Lists.hs:43:19: warning: [-Wincomplete-patterns]
Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
In a case alternative: Patterns not matched: [_]
   |
43 | continuous list = case list of 
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
```

Answer (score 5):

The warning notes, that your pattern matching is not exhaustive, since you are missing the case for a list with a single element, `[x]` for example.

Additionally, if you add a case for a single element, the case `[x,y]` is not needed anymore, since it is also handled by the case `x:y:xs`, because `xs` can also represent an empty list